# Launching cab file from Visual C++ dll

Tags: visual-c++, windows-mobile, compact-framework, cabwiz

Does anybody know how to launch a cab file from a Visual C++ dll thats being used as a setup dll when installing an application on windows mobile.
Basically, I need the dll to detect if compact framework is not installed and run required cab file if needed.

I've beeg googling for something similar for ages with no luck. Surely this has been done and there are some examples out there.
Your help is very very very much appreciated.
Tony

Comment: What do you mean by running a cab file? It's just an archive AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your talking about windows mobile cab file then Ants answer is incorrect.

You need to run the [wceload.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158700.aspx) tool to start a install of a windows mobile cab file on the WM device.

Answer (score 1):

You don't "launch" a .CAB file. You extract files out of it.

Here's a Microsoft KB article about one way to extract files out of a CAB.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189085